# Complex Riddle - Who ami I?

Tags: riddle

> I have one eye,
>
> I make dreams a reality,
>
> Doing so since the being of time.
>
> Forming life as we know it.

**Who am I?**

Comment: This riddle looks like it could be something good, but it's a bit too vague; if you tightened it up a bit, this could be a really good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sure it could be a lot of things but

> Achiever

I have one eye,

> One "i"

I make dreams a reality,

> They are the ones who get things done

Doing so since the being of time.

> Achievers since the beginning of time

Forming life as we know it.

> They are the ones who "achieve" inventions